# where can I digitally buy the soundtrack of Food Wars?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

I'm having an hard time finding where can I download/buy the soundtrack from the season 2 of Food Wars. Preferably in CD quality.

Do you know where should I look?

Comment: I assume it is *[Ni no Sara Original Soundtrack](https://shokugekinosoma.fandom.com/wiki/Ni_no_Sara_Original_Soundtrack)*? Excluding legally-questionable streaming/download sites, I'm afraid it's only released as a bonus CD from buying [the limited first release of the 3rd Blu-ray set](http://shokugekinosoma.com/2ndplate/bddvd/03.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in https://vgmdb.net/ to get info about the soundtrack (like the distribution information).

Example: [Food Wars All Albums](https://vgmdb.net/product/4104),  [Food Wars Second Plate Albums](https://vgmdb.net/product/4105)

You can also use the catalog number associated with the album to google search.

You can also directly visit the anime shows official website to get information regarding the ost of the series. But, obviously the site will be in Japanese.

Example: [Official Site](http://shokugekinosoma.com/2ndplate/music/op/op.html)

Try,

- [CDJapan](https://www.cdjapan.co.jp/series/4236?term.media_format=cdnomaxi&page=1)
- [Ark Square](https://arksquare.net/list.php?comp=Kato,%20Tatsuya)
- [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/a4all/sets/shokugeki-no-soma-season-2-ost)

Sometimes an OST will be released in with Blu-Ray/DVD release (Check the official site/twitter for this information). Other options you could try would be YouTube, Amazon and itunes. But, it depends if it is being distributed in your region. If it is not then you will have to buy or import the physical copy from another site or third party vendor.